# After every "n" chars add space, don't count if first char is zero

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this code in js. It change my input value. It delete all white spaces and then after every second char it add one empty space.

```
var value = $(input).val().replace(/(\s)/g, '').replace(/(\d{2})/g, '$1 ');
```

`1234` change into `12 34` or

`1234568790` into `12 34 56 78 90`

That code works good.
My problem is - I don't know how to exclude zero, but only if it is on first place.

For example I want this

`011111` change into `011 11 1`

`0000000` change into `000 00 00`

`01234568790` into `012 34 56 78 90`

`111000` into `11 10 00`

`012034000` into `012 03 40 00`

Input can be longer, than my examples. (I will use more chars, but for now imagine only numbers)

How can I edit my regex? (I know how to do it without regex)

Comment: Can you add few more examples to clarify your splitting rules?

Comment: I have added more examples

Comment: That's javascript right? I'm asking because a lookbehind would solve this easily, but that feature has only been implemented recently on JS engines and you might want to avoid an answer based on it.

Comment: Lookbehind regex : `.replace(/([1-9]\d|(?<!^)\d{2})/g, '$1 ')`

Comment: yes, i am searching for regex

Comment: Maybe `s.replace(/(?:^0)?\d{2}(?!$)/g, '$& ')` or `s.replace(/(?:^0)?.{2}(?!$)/g, '$& ')`? Do you need to check if the whole string is digits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not have to validate the string for only digits you may use

```
s.replace(/(?:^0)?.{2}(?!$)/g, '$& ')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p1ltVX/2).

**Details**

- `(?:^0)?` - an optional occurrence of `0` at the start of the string
- `.{2}` - any 2 chars other than line break chars
- `(?!$)` - not at the end of the string.

The `$&` in the replacement string is the whole match backreference.

If you need to check the string first, do it with `if (/^\d+$/.test(str)) {...}` and then apply this regex.

JS demo:

```js
var strs = ['1234568790', '012345', '0000000'];
for (var i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
  console.log(strs[i].replace(/(?:^0)?\d{2}(?!$)/g, '$& '));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just include an alternative check if the string starts with zero to split after the first 3 digits and otherwise split on 2 digits.

```js
let s = '01234568790';
s = s.replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/(^0\d{2}|\d{2})/g, '$1 ');
console.log(s);
// 012 34 56 87 90
```

Answer (score 1):

`(0?..)(..)*(.)?`

This regex optionally matches 0 in the first place, with 2 more characters behind it, and then matches as many groups of length 2 as it needs to, followed by an optional match of length 1. You can then loop through the matches and add a space after each one.

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/DUNr6B/2/)

Comment: nice and easy :)